# SQL Server replace sub query with @parameter

Tags: sql-server

i have follow sub query in WHERE

```
AND (
            EXISTS (
                SELECT 1
                FROM SHEMA.TABLE c
                CROSS APPLY [SHEMA].[Split](';', c.Configuration) s
                WHERE c.Id = ISNULL(@ConfigId, 1)
                    AND LEFT(s.Value, CHARINDEX(',', s.Value, 0) - 1) = RCC.ReportGroupComponentsId
                    AND RIGHT(Value, LEN(Value) - CHARINDEX(',', Value, 0)) = RCC.ReportComponentsId
                )
            OR RCC.Id IS NULL
            )
```

How can i replace reading from SHEMA.TABLE with string parameter that will have all the data needed for split?

Parameter will be in format `'1315,1609;1315,250;1315,251;1315,252'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At a total guess, I think you want:

```
AND EXISTS(SELECT 1
           FROM (VALUES(@parameter))c(Configuration)
                 CROSS APPLY [SHEMA].[Split](';', c.Configuration) s
           WHERE...) --without c.Id = ISNULL(@ConfigId, 1) as C.Id doesn't exist
```

*Side note, I hope that your object `[SHEMA].[Split]` is an inline table-value function and not a multi-line table-value function with a `WHILE`.*